# Hibernate proxy doesn't always load the object

Tags: hibernate, proxy

I have a Hibernate entity that I have been using for a while without any problems. I've added some code to guard a method (that worked without any problems) with a state variable, setting and clearing the state in a separate transaction. This has given me problems in the method accessing local private variables in the same class. Previously I could access these variables directlty, but now I must use the get methods to retrieve the variables, otherwise I get the unloaded values of those variables.

Below is the initial code that worked

- open a transaction
- fetch the object thru Hibernate
- call a method (doTheWork())
- reference the private variable
- I see the saved value of the variable, NOT the value it is initialized to (1)

  ```
      public class Desktop
      {
          public static void main()
      {
          String tx = createTransaction();
          Desktop desktop = getDesktop(tx);
          desktop.doTheWork();
          commitTransaction(tx);
      }

      private static Desktop getDesktop(String tx)
      {
          return (Desktop)txFactory.getSession(tx).load(Desktop.class, 5L);
      }
      Long nextVersion = new Long(1);

  public Long getNextVersion()
  {
      return nextVersion;
  }

  public void doTheWork()
  {
      Log.info("Value of nextVersion is " + nextVersion);
  }
  ```

  }

Below is the changed code

- open a transaction and fetch the object
- call the method
- set the state variable in a separate transaction
- open another transaction and fetch a copy of this object in the new transaction
- call (essentially) the same method (doTheWorkImpl())
- now I see the initialized value of the variable (1) rather than the persisted one.

  public class Desktop

  ```
  public static void main()
  {
      String tx = createTransaction();  // Hibernate transaction
      Desktop desktop = getDesktop(tx);  // Fetch object using Hibernate
      desktop.doTheWork();
      commitTransaction(tx);
  }
  ```

  Long nextVersion = new Long(1);

  ```
  public Long getNextVersion()
  {
      return nextVersion;
  }

  private void doTheWork()
  {
      String tx = createTransaction();
      setState(State.BUSY);
      commitTransaction(tx);

      tx = createTransaction();
      Desktop desktop = getDesktop(tx);
      desktop.doTheWorkImpl();
      commitTransaction(tx);

      tx = createTransaction();
      setState(State.NORMAL);
      commitTransaction(tx);
  }

  private void doTheWorkImpl()
  {
      Log.info("Value of nextVersion is " + nextVersion);
  }
  ```

  }

If I change the direct reference to the variable to call getNextVersion(), I see the correct value.

I understand that Hibernate uses proxies, but I don't understand why this code worked previously and now I need to force the load of the proxy. We have a lot of Hibernate objects that work essentially the same (directly referencing variables after being loaded thru Hibernate), so I'd like to understand what I introduced here that would change the pattern.

I saw an answer on here that suggested using a session.get() rather than a session.load(), but we have always used load, as this code above does.

Comment: Your question is incomplete.  You did not provide the implementation of `getDesktop()` nor show how or where you are calling `doTheWorkImpl()`.  Also, the code you presented appears to be using nested transactions, which Hibernate does not support.

Comment: Yes - it is a nested transaction - I did not know it was not supported